# Blender crashes when trying to render the Splash Fox file

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I installed Blender 3.5, from the Software Manager,  on a fresh Linux Mint installation.

I downloaded the sample [Splash Fox](https://cloud.blender.org/p/gallery/5f4cd4441b96699a87f70fcb) file from the official blender site.

The application crashes every time I try to render this. Initially I thought it was the resolution since it was set to 2k x 1k. I reduced it to 50% and it still crashes.

The crash happens for this particular file, I tried rendering a still image of other splash screen files and they were good.

I then started Blender from command line, opened the said file and hit render.

Here is the output from the terminal:

[image: Output from the terminal]

Here is my system configuration:

[image: Sys Info]

**Update**
Tried reducing the resolution as suggested. Still crashes:

[image]

[image]

What can I do to render this file?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes it crash because of the resolution %, what does it give if instead of 50% you reduce the resolution itself?

Comment: Crashes with that too. Added the image settings in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 3.5 to render a file made in version 2.90. Those are more than 3 years apart. Blender is constantly changing and improving and there is a huge difference between these versions. While you can usually open files made in earlier versions just fine, sometimes problems like this happen. This is not supposed to be surprising.

You can always download any version of Blender from https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/

It's best to render files with the version they were created in to avoid problems like this and even visual changes. Renders may look different in different versions even if rendering happens to work. Shaders, render engines, procedural textures and other functionality related to rendering may differ in different versions.